# Unable to write case statement in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have written below query in Spark SQL using `spark-shell` and I am getting below error message

```
spark.sql(""" select case when Treatment == 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end AS 'All-Yes' from person """)
```

Error message-

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input ''All-Yes'' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 58).
```

Can someone please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

The alias should be enclosed with backquotes

```sql
select case when Treatment == 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end AS `All-Yes` from person
```

though in general you shouldn't use non-standard, an incompatible names.